# Does compression expressjs module the job?

Tags: express, compression

I am using the [Compression Middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) with `Express 4`.
I just tested the `Google PageSpeed Insight` tool on my web app and it told me that I should enable the compression.

I was using:

```
var compress = require('compression')();
app.use(compress);
```

I got an error when trying to pass arguments:

```
app.use(compress({ threshold: 0 }));

/node_modules/compression/index.js:58
    var accept = req.headers['accept-encoding']
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'accept-encoding' of undefined
```

Am I missing something that are causing these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the () when defining compress:

```
var compress = require('compression');
```

Use it like so:

```
app.use(compress());
```

or

```
app.use(compress({ threshold: 0 }));
```

Like this, you shouldn't get any error.

As for me, I don't get to have it compressed in the Browser anyway.
I don't see 'Content-Encoding' in my response header and PageSpeed still advise me to compress the content.

Comment: You are right, we don't get any error this way but still not compress anything...